# Example of ring(s) with precisely 2 maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am looking for examples of ring(s) with precisely 2 maximal ideals. Anyone know of any, or how I should look for them? Just need examples of rings with this property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The product of two fields will always have this property. For example $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb Q$, or $\mathbb{Z}/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}/(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(6)$.

Comment: How you approach this problem? I just started reading ring theory(Had my first course in group theory) . I am interested in knowing your approach.

Comment: What will happen if we generalise to n maximal?

Comment: @blueboy Well, to be honest this is just a fact that I already knew when I wrote the answer. To the extent that I had an "approach", I'm afraid it's a very abstract one: To every commutative ring $R$, you can associate a topological space (actually an affine scheme) $\text{Spec}(R)$ consisting of all of the prime ideals of $R$. The maximal ideals are the closed points of this space. Now product of rings corresponds to disjoint union of Specs. So $\text{Spec}(R\times S) = \text{Spec}(R) \sqcup \text{Spec}(S)$. The closed points of the disjoint union are exactly the closed points of the pieces.

Comment: Ok... Its beyond my understanding for now. Well come back at it after a year or so :)

Comment: So whenever $R$ and $S$ each have a unique maximal ideal, $R\times S$ will have exactly two maximal ideals. The fact above answers your question about $n$ maximal ideals: A product of $n$ fields (or any $n$ commutative rings each with a unique maximal ideal) will have exactly $n$ maximal ideals. Interestingly, this does not generalize to the infinite. A product $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} k_n$, where each $k_n$ is a field, has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ maximal ideals! These maximal ideals are in bijection with the *ultrafilters* on $\mathbb{N}$. @blueboy

Answer (score 6):

Alex's answer works. But in general given a ring $R$, find an ideal $I$ that is contained in exactly two maximal ideals and then consider the quotient $R/I$. You know by one of the isomorphism theorems that the maximal ideals of $R/I$ are simply the maximal ideals of $R$ containing the ideal $I$. More concretely, if you know two maximal ideals, you could just take their product!

Live example: Let $R=k[x]$, $m_1=(x)$ and $m_2=(x-1)$. Then let $I=m_1m_2=(x(x-1))$. Then the ring $k[x]/(x(x-1))$ has exactly two maximal ideals.

Comment: Yes, this is a more general way of coming up with examples. But note that your example $k[x]/(x(x-1))$ is isomorphic to the product of fields $k^2$, since $(x(x-1))$ is the kernel of the map $k[x]\to k^2$ given by $p(x) \mapsto (p(0),p(1))$. In general, if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are maximal ideals in $R$, then $R/(m_1\cap m_2)$ is a product of fields $R/m_1\times R/m_2$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Haha you are right. It seems that my quest for generality has clouded my short term sight. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**1.** See my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627832/commutative-domain-with-two-maximal-ideals-of-different-heights/1627925#1627925) question, which has more. You can generalize it to the ring that has any number of finite maximal ideals.

---

**2.** *Gilmer* 's book *Multiplicative Ideal Theory* Th(22.8) has:
let $V_1, \cdots, V_n$ be a finite collection of valuation rings on a field $K$ s.t. $V_i\nsubseteq V_j$. Let $V=\cap V_i$. Then $V$ is a prufer domain Which has exactly $n$ maximal ideals.